# Why does passing view model bindings through a conditional statement cause the view to stop refreshing?

Tags: mvvm, binding, swiftui, viewmodel

I'm making a SwiftUI app using MVVM. My view model is an observable object which I declare in the parent view as an @StateObject and I pass down bindings to child view components such as pickers. My understanding is that when bindings in the child view change this updates the view model which as an @StateObject refreshes the parent view and in turn refreshes the child view, and this has been working fine.

**However** if somewhere in the main view I pass the view model through a conditional statement, none of the child views refresh when their bindings change anymore. Even if they are outside of the conditional statement. It's as if a new view model has been created for the condition.

My question is why is this happening and is there something wrong in my approach? For example is it bad practice to put conditional logic in the view (if so what is best practice for dealing with minor variations)? Or do you always need to pass down the whole view model to child components instead of just bindings (if so how do you make your components reusable in different contexts)? I have found some work arounds but am more interested in understanding the issue and adopting practices that will avoid it in the future.

I have created a minimal reproducible version of the code below, if the condition in content view is true when you select items from the picker the view updates. When the condition is false it does not.

Thanks so much for your help!

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bindingArray: [Int] = [0,1]
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    init(){
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // bindings break when the if condition is true (changing it to 1 != 1 will make them work again)
                if 1 == 1 {
                    BlankBindingView(bindingArray: $viewModel.bindingArray)
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: PickerList(bindingArray: $viewModel.bindingArray)){
                    Text("Tap me")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct BlankBindingView: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        Text("Condition is true, bindings will not work")
    }
}

struct PickerList: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    @State private var allArray: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("If the bindings are working checkmarks should appear when you tap a row")
            ForEach(allArray, id: \.self){ i in
                Button(action: {self.bindingArray.append(i)}){
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(i))
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: self.bindingArray.contains(i) ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has more to do with the fact that you are sending the view model array (Does not happen with an `@State` array) to two `@Binding` vs the conditional itself. If you put the same code in the `else` it does not work either.

If that is by design or a bug only Apple can tell you. I would be curious to see if the same happens with a CoreData object. I tried manually activating the `viewModel.objectWillChange.send()` with no success so I am inclined to say it is a bug worth reporting.

The list is being updated (hit `Back` and then go back to the `List`) the `View` just isn't getting the refresh.

Passing the `viewModel` and using `@EnviromentObject` is a workaround.

```
import SwiftUI


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bindingArray: [Int] = [0,1]
}


struct ConditoinalView: View {
    @State var bindingArray: [Int] = [0,1]
    @StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    init(){
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // bindings break when the if condition is true (changing it to 1 != 1 will make them work again)
                
                if 1 == 1{
                    //viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
                    //Does not work if the viewModel.bindingArray is shared by 2 @Binding in the same View
                    
                    BlankBindingView(bindingArray: $viewModel.bindingArray)
                    BlankBindingViewEO().environmentObject(viewModel)
                    BlankBindingViewState(bindingArray: $bindingArray)
                }else{
                    //@Binding will not work either
                    BlankBindingView(bindingArray: $viewModel.bindingArray)
                    BlankBindingViewEO().environmentObject(viewModel)
                    BlankBindingViewState(bindingArray: $bindingArray)
                    
                }
                //Shared Breaks when shared @Binding
                NavigationLink(destination: PickerList(bindingArray: $viewModel.bindingArray, action: {//Tell vm there is a change
                                                        viewModel.objectWillChange.send()})
                ){
                    Text("Tap me")
                }
                //Does not break
                NavigationLink(destination: PickerListEO().environmentObject(viewModel)
                ){
                    Text("Tap me EO")
                }
                //Does not break
                NavigationLink(destination: PickerListState(bindingArray: $bindingArray)){
                    Text("Tap me State")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
struct BlankBindingView: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        Text("BlankBindingView count = \(bindingArray.count)")
        Text("Condition is true, bindings will not work")
    }
}
struct BlankBindingViewState: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    var body: some View {
        Text("BlankBindingViewState count = \(bindingArray.count)")
        Text("Condition is true, bindings WILL work")
    }
}
struct BlankBindingViewEO: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("BlankBindingViewEO count = \(vm.bindingArray.count)")
        Text("Condition is true, bindings WILL work")
    }
}
struct PickerList: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    @State private var allArray: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        List {
            //The array is being updated (go back and then return) but the View isnt being updated
            Text("If the bindings are working checkmarks should appear when you tap a row")
            Text("PickerList count = \(bindingArray.count)")
            ForEach(allArray, id: \.self){ i in
                Button(action: {self.bindingArray.append(i)
                    //Tell VM there is a change
                    action()
                }){
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(i))
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: self.bindingArray.contains(i) ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PickerListEO: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    @State private var allArray: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("If the bindings are working checkmarks should appear when you tap a row")
            Text("PickerListEO count = \(vm.bindingArray.count)")
            ForEach(allArray, id: \.self){ i in
                Button(action: {self.vm.bindingArray.append(i)}){
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(i))
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: self.vm.bindingArray.contains(i) ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct PickerListState: View {
    @Binding var bindingArray: [Int]
    @State private var allArray: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("If the bindings are working checkmarks should appear when you tap a row")
            Text("PickerListState count = \(bindingArray.count)")
            ForEach(allArray, id: \.self){ i in
                Button(action: {self.bindingArray.append(i)}){
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(i))
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: self.bindingArray.contains(i) ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ConditoinalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConditoinalView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks loremipsum - I’m not sure the issue can be with sending the vm to two bindings though, because if you remove the conditional clause from the original code and duplicate the picker a few times they all work. It’s interesting you mention coredata - my original code has an array of coredata objects instead of an array of ints and that doesn’t work either. I can’t use environment object unfortunately as I need to create multiple instances of the view model.

Comment: It looks like Form and a conditional it doesn’t seem to happen in a VStack

Comment: oh that's a great spot - even just wrapping the conditional statement in a vstack and keeping the form works. very practical workaround. d'you think its just an apple bug then?

Comment: Probably, or something to do with the Form features

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the viewModel into the child view instead of the Binding

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bindingArray: [Int] = [0,1]
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel
    init(){
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel())
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // bindings break when the if condition is true (changing it to 1 != 1 will make them work again)
                if 1 == 1 {
                    BlankBindingView(viewModel: viewModel)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: PickerList(viewModel: viewModel)){
                    Text("Tap me")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BlankBindingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("Condition is true, bindings will not work")
    }
}

struct PickerList: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State private var allArray: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("If the bindings are working checkmarks should appear when you tap a row")
            ForEach(allArray, id: \.self){ i in
                Button(action: {viewModel.bindingArray.append(i)}){
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(i))
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: viewModel.bindingArray.contains(i) ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Volker88 - I considered passing the whole view model to the picker but then it’s harder to re-use in other contexts. In reality I have multiple view models and the picker is a custom multi-choice picker with a search. I was hoping I could use it freely by passing a binding, in the same way I use the built in picker. Idk maybe that’s just not possible - would you say it’s standard practice to pass the whole view model? I’m new to MVVM so trying to get a grip on best practices